# getting error while getting channel name in twilio. Here i am implementing one to one chat

Tags: android, twilio

I am getting always error while checking channel name like

```
mChatClient.getChannels().getChannel("one", new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
            if (channel != null) {
                joinChannel(channel);
            } else {
                mChatClient.getChannels().createChannel("one",
                        Channel.ChannelType.PUBLIC, new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                                if (channel != null) {
                                    joinChannel(channel);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                                Log.e(TAG,"Error creating channel: " + errorInfo.getErrorText());
                            }
                        });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Error retrieving channel: " + errorInfo.getErrorText());
        }

    });
```

in this always coming to error block only. May i know what is the wrong?

Comment: Add the exception message.

Comment: errorInfo.getErrorText()); getting empty message i.e  E/TwilioChat: Error retrieving channel: error code is 404

Comment: Well looks like channel named `one` does not exist.

Comment: in above code what i am doing is 1. checking channel available or not. 2.if available join the channel otherwise creating that channel . But i am getting error response.  Can u tell how to modify code

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is:

1. Checking if the channel is available or not.
2. If available check if the channel is null and if so create the channel.

If you look at the code you see you are doing the create in the `onSuccess`, however, if your channel can't be found, `onSuccess` is never triggered, so it won't try to create the channel.

What you should do instead is in the `onError` create the channel. (untested, might be some errors):

```
mChatClient.getChannels().getChannel("one", new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
        joinChannel(channel);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error retrieving channel: " + errorInfo.getErrorText());
        mChatClient.getChannels().createChannel("one", Channel.ChannelType.PUBLIC, new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                if (channel != null) {
                    joinChannel(channel);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error creating channel: " + errorInfo.getErrorText());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and every time its going to onerror only even after created channel in first time onerror method

Answer (score 1):

As already answered we need to create channel in onerror() but that would lead to creating new channel each time.
Reason behind creating new channel each time is because we are comparing with **unique name** in getchannel() method; whereas the one we set in createChannel() method is **friendly name**. Try setting uniquename of the channel on success. Alternately you may try this code:

```
 mChatClient.getChannels().getChannel("general", new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                if (channel != null) {
                    joinChannel(channel);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Error retrieving channel: " + errorInfo.getMessage());
                mChatClient.getChannels().channelBuilder().withUniqueName("general").withType(Channel.ChannelType.PUBLIC).build(new CallbackListener<Channel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Channel channel) {
                        if (channel != null) {


                            joinChannel(channel);


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"Error creating channel: " + errorInfo.getMessage());
                    }
                });


            }
        });
```